# Rails : form select helper to have a starting default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, helper

I have a simple form.
Also as part of the form I have a variable with an array/list of all the country names.
The form picks up the list just fine, however, it starts off on the first value, I think its `Afghanistan`, however I want it to start/default with `United Kingdom`

This is my code for the form select for the countries.

```
<%= f.select(:country, @country_list.map { |value| [ value, value ] }) %>
```

I have tried without success:

```
<%= f.select(:country, @country_list.map { |value| [ value, value ] },['United Kingdom']) %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried selected option

```
:selected =>  "United Kingdom" or your_country_id
```

not sure about the syntax but hopefully it would work

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select):

> Specify :selected => value to use a different selection or :selected => nil to leave all options unselected.

So if you want the default to be selected, try this:

```
f.select(:country, @country_list.map { |value| [ value, value ] }, selected: "United Kingdom")
```

Comment: syntax should be `:selected => 'value'`

Comment: That's equivalent to `selected: 'value'` in ruby 1.9